# C# XNA colliders, physics, inclined plane/terrain/colliders

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection, physics

Currently I'm working on a project to learn game programming. But I'm not sure if I have the right approach on several things, and that's what I'm here for.

What I'm trying to create is a small world in 3d and simulate some simple physics. The world can be seen below.

[image]
The world is basically a box, note that I've left out the walls in the front and side view, but they will be there. The goal is to drop a ball somewhere in the green area and let physics do its work. Then the simulation will end once the ball falls into the hole. Later, once I got a better understanding of everything I want to create a pinball game out of it, but that's for a later stage.

Currently I'm creating this project in C# XNA/MonoDevelop and want to create everything from scratch. So I got my own physics engine, collider classes, math library, et cetera, which I find quite challenging, especially since I knew/know nothing about all of this, especially the math, but I am learning a lot from it, and I find it a lot of fun!

So what do I have now:

I got a GameObject class, which contains a position, a model, update and draw methods, etc. And a Physics Engine which uses PhysicsObjects and ModelObjects (both inheriting from the GameObject).

The PhysicsObject contains a mass, velocity, gravity, a collider update and draw method and the ModelObject just has a position and a collider and update and draw method.

The PhysicsEngine has a Run(deltatime) method which is being called in the update method and integrates through all the PhysicsObjects in step one, updating it's velocity, applying gravity, and finally position. In the next step the PhysicsEngine handles the collisions. It checks whether a collision was found between PhysicsObjects and PhysicsObjects and PhysicsObjects and ModelObjects and if a collision was detected it will handle the collision response.

So far I only have an Axis-Aligned Bounding Box, BoundingSphere and Plane class. And implemented the Sphere-Sphere collision, and Sphere-Plane collision.

I soon realized the AABB wouldn't be possible since I can't rotate them. So I tried creating planes, since as far as I understand, a Plane exists out of a normal vector to determine the 'up' side and a distance from the center/origin. The problem only is that there isn't a begin or end position so I can't have a hole in the terrain. So this is where I'm stuck, I have no idea on how to approach this and what to use and how most people would solve this problem. I'm not asking for code snippets or anything, but want to know if my general approach to all of this is 'correct' and how I should approach this problem for the terrain. What kind of collider should I use for the terrain to also make it possible to rotate it?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a hole in a plane. If you know the geometric center of the hole, simply place a condition on the ball/plane collision such that if that ball is on the plane but is within half width and half length of the center of the hole, then act as if the plane is not there.

You can set the edges of the structure on the plane in a similar fashion.